# Python using array twice results in wrong return value

Tags: python, flask

Okay, so I am working on a project where there is a website, that can calculate how much profit you can make from each item from a video game!

I ran into a few issues down the road but managed to solve a few of them, both myself and got help here on StackOverflow. Now the issue I am at right now, I cant seem to figure out.

I am trying to get a "total cost" of products, which I do by doing this (code: 1):

```
total = []
for x in range(len(buy)):
    total.append(amount[x] * sell[x])
```

I get 'amount' from this code right here(code: 2):

```
amount = []
for x in range(len(buy)):
   amount.append(userInput / sell[x])
```

Now the issue is that whenever I try to get the total cost, it pretty much just straight up copies whatever the user have put in, and I am guessing it does so because of the -

```
amount.append(userInput / sell[x])
```

When I am trying to reach that "amount" from an different for loop, it causes issues? I might be completely wrong here, and that's why I need your help! :)

Here is the full code of the page:

```
@app.route('/bflipper', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def bFlipper():
    product_name = []
    f = requests.get(
        'https://api.hypixel.net/skyblock/bazaar?key=73ac0a44-4c41-4933-a9ee-b4095be2b6d2').json()
    for x in productNames:
        product_name.append(f["products"][x]["product_id"])
    if request.method == 'POST':
        userInput = request.form['coins']
        userInput = int(userInput)
        sell = [product['sell_summary'][0]['pricePerUnit']
                for product in f['products'].values() if product['sell_summary']]

        buy = [product['buy_summary'][0]['pricePerUnit']
               for product in f['products'].values() if product['buy_summary']]

        amount = []
        for x in range(len(buy)):
            totAmount = userInput / sell[x]
            amount.append(totAmount)

        total = []
        for x in range(len(buy)):
            total.append(amount[x] * sell[x])

        return render_template("flipper.html", userInput=userInput, product_name=product_name, amount=amount, total=total, sell=sell, buy=buy)
    else:
        return render_template("flipper.html", product_name=product_name)
```

Here is how it looks on the page:

[image: picture]

I wrote in '123321' as an 'userInput', and you can see on 'total cost' that it pretty much copied what I put in, so somewhere in 'code:1 & code:2' it is causing issues!

Thanks!
- Simon

Comment: Can you explain, in English, what is the logic behind the computations? I guess this is from a game and user has some balance i.e. 123321 and you go through products and first calculate how many (i.e. amount) product user can "buy" (even though you do this computation over `sell`). Then I fail to see the rationale for computation  of `Total Cost` in the table i.e. how should it be calculated?

Comment: sorry, I am a bit confused about "sell" and "buy" as well. So I saw that a few minutes ago, "sell" is somehow connected to "buy", and the opposite. So "sell" carries "buy"s values. I got help down below, and I think I know how to solve the issue. It is pretty hard to explain something like this when it is surrounded by a game you need to know a little about. I was hoping to get an answer WHY it showed "123321" on the table, when I did put in "123321" in variable "userinput", and I got my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`total` ends up as copies of `userInput` because that's exactly what you programmed it to do. Walking through this: at each index, what is `amount[x]`? Well, you set it equal to `userInput / sell[x]`. So, what will each of `total[x]` be? `total[x] == amount[x] * sell[x] == (userInput / sell[x]) * sell[x] == userInput` (roughly, with some floating point imprecision visible in your screenshot). So, all of the entries in `total` end up as copies of `userInput` like you observed.

In conclusion, I'm not sure that "using the array twice" is necessarily the issue here. I don't know what your code is supposed to do, but this is why it's doing what it is.

Comment: Yeah I probably stared at that title for a good minute or two, didn't really know how I could explain this. Also, I see that to make sense when you put it like that! I also tried to make two separate "amounts" and well, as you might understand that didn't really work out. Can I somehow get around the issue by not making 'total' & 'amount' arrays? And instead having it constantly updating a variable?

Comment: I saw that using "arrays" for float values in flask helped a lot, as I can get around the issue: "TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable". I've worked on this website for a few days and still don't understand how to get around it.

Comment: @SimonSjöö it seems to me that `total` and `amount` **need** to be arrays in order to be displayed in the table like that. It is up to you to decide what data goes in them, and what "total cost" means in the context of your application.

Comment: Yeah I got it to work, just didn't see the `total[x] == amount[x] * sell[x] == (userInput / sell[x]) * sell[x] == userInput` in my head, so I got really confused on why its showing that. Anyways, thanks for the help!